How to distinguish the incoming packets group when joining multiple multicast feeds in UdpSocket
I need to listen 2 UDP multicast addresses. One is 233.113.216.75:21001 and the other is 233.113.216.70:21001. Due to their ports are same I can't bind to them separately.
use std::net::UdpSocket;

let socket = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:21001").unwrap();
udp_socket.join_multicast_v4(&Ipv4Addr::new(233, 113, 216, 70), &Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED)?;
udp_socket.join_multicast_v4(&Ipv4Addr::new(233, 113, 216, 75), &Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED)?;

I can listen both of the feed with udp_socket.recv_from(&mut self.buffer) without any issues. However, I can't know the incoming packet's multicast group. recv_from returns the IP address of the client, not the multicast group. I need to know which group the incoming packet is belong to.
Is there any way to get the multicast group of the incoming datagram?
Thanks for your help in advance.
I tried to use the addr from recv_from, but it shows the source IP address.

Due to their ports are same I can't bind to them separately., The IP:Port is unique, you can bind on that.

You can create multiple sockets and bind them on (multicast-group, port) separately. Each socket will then take traffic (and only multicast traffic) on its respective multicast group, even though port is the same for all groups. Restriction applies only when INADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0) is used or when the (multicast-group., port) pair is the same and then you have to go through SO_REUSEADDR option

I tried to bind 0.0.0.0:21001 multiple times but it didn't work. If I change the second one to 0.0.0.0:21002, then it didn't receive the messages from multicast. How can I bind the second one?

Don't bind to 0.0.0.0, instead bind to 233.113.216.70:21001 and 233.113.216.75:21001.

@Jmb Thanks! It worked

The underlying C API allow setting the IP_PKTINFO socket option so that a call to recvmsg will include metadata containing the destination IP of the packet.  Not sure if rust exposes this API.

@Jmb 's answer in the comment fixes the issue.

Don't bind to 0.0.0.0, instead bind to 233.113.216.70:21001 and
233.113.216.75:21001.

